# Difference between sed and grep usage in find command pattern matching

Tags: sed, grep, find, regular-expression

I'm trying to understand why I cannot use `sed` in the following example.

I'm having a nested folder structure where all folders contain a text file called `PKGBUILD`. I want to only print out the relative path of the files containing a certain pattern, e.g., `pkgname=.*dbus`

If I use `find` in conjunction with `grep` I get the expected output, i.e.,

```
find . -name 'PKGBUILD' -exec grep -q 'pkgname=.*dbus' {} \; -print
```

I correctly get

```
./packages/dbus-python/repos/extra-x86_64/PKGBUILD
./packages/dbus-python/trunk/PKGBUILD
./packages/dbus-glib/repos/extra-x86_64/PKGBUILD
./packages/dbus-glib/trunk/PKGBUILD
```

as output of the relative filepath, since only those `PKGBUILD` files contain the correct pattern.
As far as I understand the `-q` option in grep is responsible for omitting the print as long as there is no match found.

However I should be able to emulate the same behavior by using `sed`.
I use it in the following way

```
find . -name 'PKGBUILD' -exec sed -n '/pkgname.*dbus/q' {} \; -print
```

where `-n` is used to omit output and `q` to quit immediately when the match is found.
However, this command outputs **every** `PKGBUILD` file in the tree, regardless if `sed` matches anything.
Why is the behavior of `grep` and `sed` here so different and how would I make the `sed` command work?

Comment: `find` uses the exit status of the `-exec command` to decide whether to continue with the `-print`. `grep` status depends on whether any matches occurred, but `sed` status does not.

Comment: I used GNU `sed` and in the man page it states, that you can adjust the exit-code of `sed`. E.g. using `sed -n '/pkgname.*dbus/q0`. However the result is the same.  Does `sed` print any invisible output to `stdout`? `grep -q` explicitly states that nothing is printed to `stdout` until a match is found.

Comment: @don_crissti the `grep` solution works fine. This is a conceptual question challenging my understanding of the two programs.

Comment: @Invarianz using `q0` doesn't really help since 0 is the default exit status - you'd need to set a *non*-zero exit status on *non*-match. I haven't really thought it through but perhaps `sed -n -e '/pkgname.*dbus/q' -e '$q1'` ?

Comment: @steeldriver that makes a lot of sense. However, the suggested command does not work and still prints everything. I guess to make the logic work I'd need to return 1 on non-match as you suggested. I would happily accept the answer if it works!

Comment: Already tried that @don_crissti, this omits the correct paths since it returns code 1 on the match. So it prints everything *but* the matches

Comment: You're right. Sorry for the wrong statement. I didn't know that you can negate the return code of the -exec in find in such a way. This is pretty cool. I would happily accept your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As all commenters have already mentioned there is a significant difference between the return status between pattern matching via `sed` or via `grep`.

Whereas `grep -q` only returns a `0` status on a found match `sed` always returns `0` regardless if a match is found or not (There are cases where a file or stream can not be read and it actually does not give `0`). Via the `sed` GNU extension this return status can be modified, i.e. we can change it such that `sed` only returns `1` when a pattern match occurs.

```
sed -n '/pkgname.*dbus/q1'
```

However the `find` program only `print`s on a return status of `0` of the previous `exec` action, i.e., we need to negate `sed`s return status using `!`.

The full `find` command using `sed` then reads,

```
find . -name 'PKGBUILD' ! -exec sed -n '/pkgname.*dbus/q1' {} \; -print
```

with the output

```
./packages/dbus-python/repos/extra-x86_64/PKGBUILD
./packages/dbus-python/trunk/PKGBUILD
./packages/dbus-glib/repos/extra-x86_64/PKGBUILD
./packages/dbus-glib/trunk/PKGBUILD
```

as expected. Thanks to @Paul_Pedant, @steeldriver and especially @don_crissti for the great insight!

Comment: Good! Note that in practice it's better to use `q7` or something above `4` (which are [exit codes](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Exit-status.html#Exit-status) already used by `gnu sed` for specific errors...)

Comment: This isn't quite the same as the grep version though I think? In particular, it will print the names of files for which sed exits with non-zero status for *any* reason - try it with a (non-matching) file for which you don't have read permission for example.

Comment: This is true @steeldriver . I was hoping that my mention of non-zero exit codes in case of an unreadable file or stream would be enough to highlight that the `print` in the `find` command would be triggered by `sed` in those cases also. This does **not** happen with `grep`